# Decreasing energy but at expanse of what

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

**question :** A hollow spherical shell with radius R has charge Q uniformly distributed
over it.

**(i)** show that the energy
stored in this system is $\dfrac{Q^2}{8\pi \epsilon_{0}R}.$

**(ii)** Now imagine taking all of the charge and concentrating it in two
 point charges $\dfrac{Q}{2}$ located at diametrically opposite positions on
  the shell. Then find energy of this new system

**(iii)** why does energy come less in **(ii)** than in **(i)** ? explain with reasoning

**my attempt :**

**(i)**$\ U_{1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0} \displaystyle\int E^2 dv=\dfrac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0} \displaystyle\int_{R}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r^2}\right)^2.4 \pi r^2 dr=\dfrac{Q^2}{8\pi \epsilon_{0}}\displaystyle\int_{R}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{r^2}= \dfrac{Q^2}{8\pi \epsilon_{0}R}$

(ii)$ \ U_{2}= \dfrac{Q^2}{32\pi\epsilon_0R}=25\%$  of $U_{1}$

(iii) By work energy theoram:

$\Delta U + \Delta K=0 $

i am able to see there has been change in potential energy in (ii) part of the question with respect to (i) but there is no change in Kinetic energy of charges.so,i'm unable to understand  why Work energy theoram is not working out here

**and if you claim kinetic energy of charges would have changed  then why don't they fly off the surface of spherical shell**

i need help in (iii) part ,and please provide intuitive explanation not rigor mathematics

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  You're right that kinetic energy has nothing to do with it.  Instead, try using $U = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int E^2 dv$ to figure out the energy of a *single* point charge.  The answer you get there should give you a clue as to why your answer for (ii) doesn't seem to agree with your answer for (i).